# Permission denied when trying to run C++ MySQL Script

Tags: c++, mysql, codeblocks

so I am trying to get simple code to work with access to a local MySQL Server that is being hosted with Xampp and configured with PhpMyAdmin, I simply want to establish a connection to the Server but I can't find where my problems are at!

I know I had a lot of linker errors using MySQL and Codeblocks, I have simply added MySQLServer lib to linker aswell as all Booster libs and included the MySQLServer Include files aswell as Boost Include Files,

When I try to run the script below (copy and pasted) I do get this error:

`ld.exe||cannot find C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include: Permission denied|`

What am I doing wrong? I can't run Codeblocks as Admin because I would have to log in with an Admin Account and then my Drives and every link would be gone.

I have tried for hours now with several MySQLlibs, and I am pretty desperate right now. When I have used Perl MySQL was no problem at all.

```
#include "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include\mysql.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MYSQL* conn;

    mysql_server_init(0, NULL, NULL);

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (conn == NULL) {
        cout << "Keine Datenbankinitialisierung moeglich!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "Datenbank initialisiert!\n";

    if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "root", "test", 3306, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        cout << "Datenbank test konnte nicht geoeffnet werden!\n";
        cout << "Error: " << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "datenbank test wurde geoeffnet!\n";
    cout << "\nein paar ausgaben aus der tabelle adressen der test-datenbank:\n";

    MYSQL_FIELD* field;
    MYSQL_RES* result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    unsigned long* fieldLengths;

    mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM namen");
    /* "namen" ist der Name der Tabelle auf die zugegriffen werden soll ! */

    result = mysql_store_result(conn);

    unsigned int fieldNumbers = mysql_num_fields(result);

    cout << "\nAnzahl der Spalten : " << fieldNumbers << endl;

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {
        fieldLengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldNumbers; i++) {
            if (row[i] == 0) {
                printf(" (null) ");
            }
            else {
                //printf("%s ",  row[i] );
                cout << row[i] << "  ";
            }

        } // end for

        cout << endl;

    } // end while

    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(conn);
    cout << "\nDatenbank test wurde wieder geschlossen!\n";

    mysql_server_end();
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE;  is it because I have added MYSQLServer\include to the linker list, even though those files belong to"search directories". I did this because it fixed some errors, and only came up with the "permission denied" one.

When I remove this line from the linker, I get this kind of error: `C:\Users\dzin\Desktop\c++tests\test\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to mysql_server_init@12'|`

Comment: It is interesting that `ld` is involved. I mean I would have expected a compiler error not a problem with the linker.

Comment: @drescherjm is it because I have added MYSQLServer\include to the linker list, even tho those files belong into "search directories". I did this because it fixed some errors, and only came up with the "permission denied" one. When I remove this line from the linker, I get this kind of error: `C:\Users\dzin\Desktop\c++tests\test\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to `mysql_server_init@12'|` and these are linking errors as far as I know, but I have added the MySQLServer Libs to the list..

Comment: ***I have added MYSQLServer\include to the linker list*** I think that is the wrong solution. Does `MYSQLServer\include` have static and/or dynamic libraries (seems like a bad place for those)?

Comment: Have you put the MySQL libraries (static or dynamic) into your project?  Is the linking phase processing the MySQL libraries?

Comment: I do not know, so dynamic libraries are more or less .dll files, right? I added .lib files to the linker and \include only contains .h files

Comment: Nitpick: C++ programs are /not/ scripts. C++ is a compiled language, not a runtime interpreted one.

Comment: Add the correct .lib files and remove `MYSQLServer\include` from the linker settings.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you are right, I still talk of "script" when I am talking about a less complicated, simple piece of code :), my bad